# Replace NA in row with value in adjacent row (not only one row)

Tags: r, excel

input data

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 #header
a b c d e #full data 1
NA f g NA NA
NA NA NA i NA
NA j NA NA NA k
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 #full data 2
NA NA f1 g1 NA
```

Expected output

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
a bfj cg di ek
a1 b1 c1f1 d1g1 e1
```

It is useful link:
[Replace NA in row with value in adjacent row "ROW" not column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677227/replace-na-in-row-with-value-in-adjacent-row-row-not-column)

I used a lot of for loops. OMG.. My code is very dirty.

Comment: So do you want to "concatenate each column across rows within groups, where each group begins when a row is completely populated"?

Comment: sorry.. I can't understand exactly. I don't want to change column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`. First, I identify the columns with no NAs. Then I use the cumulative count of those to define groups. Within those groups, I paste all the rows' values (excluding NA's) together.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>% mutate(full = sum(is.na(c_across()))) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(full == 0)) %>%
  summarize(across(.fns = ~paste0(na.omit(.x), collapse = ""))) %>%
  select(-group, -full)

# A tibble: 2 × 5
  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     bfj   cg    di    e    
2 a1    b1    c1f1  d1g1  e1
```

Comment: Thanks! but in my case, c_across, across function error occurs. Any other alternatives? error message : `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs. I fixed it by editing "dplyr::"summarize. Thanks !!